# AJAX response url redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function that processes a form and return a message, but i need that if the response is an URL, the process detect that and redirect to that URL.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $('#'+id_form).serialize(),
               success: function(data)
                {
                    if (data==1){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }else{
                        respuesta.innerHTML=data;
                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: if you have full control of backend, then you might want to consider restruture your message and make it more meaning. Perhaps a return type + return content in json? That will allow you to do minimal work in deciding what to do with the returned message

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to change the return values of the server side:

```
if (something)
    return Json { IsUrl = true, Data = "theUrl" };
return Json { IsUrl = false, Data = "some message" };
```

then in your ajax call:

```
success: function(data)
{
    if (data.IsUrl == true){
        window.location = data.Data;
    }else{
        respuesta.innerHTML=data.Data;
    }
}
```